# Can not build svelte-kit static pages based on md files - build error

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sveltekit, static-pages

I am trying to build static sites with svelte-kit using static-adapter, but when I try to build a project the build process end with error showing that md-parser is not present. I am using this parser for parsing md files with page content served from headless cms.

When I run this code in dev mode using node everything works fine, but when I try build it it runs into error.

```
> Using @sveltejs/adapter-static
TypeError: parseMD is not a function
```

My code index.json.js file:

```
import fs from "fs";
import parseMD from "parse-md";

export function get() {
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync("content/pages/home.md", "utf8");
  const pageData = parseMD(fileContents);
  let body = JSON.stringify(pageData);
  return {body}
}
```

And there is a index.svelte file:

```
<script context="module">
  export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const pageData = await fetch(`index.json`).then((r) => r.json());
    console.log(pageData);
    return {
      props: { pageData },
    };
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let pageData;
</script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>{pageData.metadata.text}</h1>
  {pageData.content}
</div>
```

Can you help me please? How can I parse md files without allowed 3th party lib imports in *.json.js files?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do

```
import {default as parseMD} from 'parse-md;
```

Comment: Thanks but it has have no effect :( I've already solved it by using different parser. (markdown-yaml-metadata-parser)